# Visual Studio 2022 not loading dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I seem to be having an issue with running projects after upgrading to Visual Studio 2022 and installing Net 6.0 SDK. Whenever I open an existing project or even create a new one I get the below errors with the Dependencies.

[image]

If I try building the project I get the error:

[image]

There aren't any errors in the Error list.

Tried a few things but still nothing helps :

I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2022 and Net 6.0

- Tried unloading and reloading project
- Tried clearing Nuget cache
- Tried removing bin,obj, csproj.user,.vs folder

If I try building/debugging a project in Visual Studio Code everything works normally so it doesn't seem to be an issue with the SDK.

Also noticed that I am unable to open the Nuget Package Manager UI but the .csproj file is correct and void of any errors.

Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: If you try to check Error list window as the error said,what you will get?

Comment: There is nothing in the error list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually install the SDK's manually which seems to have caused the issue.

The solution to fixing this is to uninstall all manually installed SDK packages.

Following the SDK uninstall's, reinstall the net 6.0 and/or prior releases from the Visual Studio installer.
I did a fresh install just incase.

All dependencies should load correctly now for net 6.0 projects.
If not, please delete the .vs, bin and obj folder for the specific project and open it again in VS2022 and the dependencies should load. Delete the same folders for projects on previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried `dotnet build`? that usually forces auto resolving of dependencies!

I've also faced similar issues in recent days after the final release of 2022.

Comment: I did that and the project built fine without any errors but the Dependencies are still the same with the error/warning icons. Nuget Package Manager UI is also still blank

Comment: In that case, to resolve this issue, you have to manually install that package searching out from the NuGet package library!

Comment: That's what I have been doing. Hopefully this gets automatically resolved in a future update of VS as this happens across every project

Comment: Also getting this problem in VS2022; along with the nuget browser thinking there are no packages installed or update available (even after installing a package).

Comment: @melodiouscode Please see the answer I posted

Comment: @user2806570 your fix sort of helped, in that it stopped the over the top warnings/errors. However to actually build I need VS2022 to be in admin mode.

Answer (score 1):

You may also get this problem if the path to your project contains a "%20" in the path.

This can happen if you clone a repo from Azure DevOps where the repo name has a space in it.

E.g.:

git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/company/MY%20Project/MY%20Project

Becomes:

c:\repos\MY%20Project

Remove the "%20" in the path resolves the problem:

c:\repos\MY-Project